# cannot add integers

Tags: c#, calculator

Ok so, I am fairly new to C# and I want ot add two values which a user inputs into a textbox. Here is my code and I get an error for "val1 + val2". How do I add these values? I am really sorry if this has been asked before but I have searched for an answer and I simply cannot find one. Thanks :).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Csharp_Calculator
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            textBoxAns.Text = val1 + val2;
        }

        private void buttonSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            textBoxAns.Text = val1 + val2;
        }

        private void buttonDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            textBoxAns.Text = val1 + val2;
        }

        private void buttonRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBoxAns.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best thing to do is always search on the error you are getting. The error isn't stating you can't add two numbers together.  =)

Comment: The problem is not adding two integers. The problem is assigning the resulting integer to a string property (`textBoxAns.Text`).

Comment: _Read the error message_!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
textBoxAns.Text = (val1 + val2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
textBoxAns.Text = (val1 + val2).ToString();
```

Generally in C#, you cannot implicitly convert a numeric to a `string` so just wrap the brackets around and it will do the calculations first then put the result as a string afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Your sum of `val1 + val2` is an integer. To solve this, you'll have to convert the sum into what is readable by the text box, so:

```
textBoxAns.Text = Convert.ToString(val1 + val2);
```

Some programmers prefer int.ToString also. In such a case, just do:

```
textBoxAns.Text = (val1 + val2).ToString();
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of the problem. However for the solution I would go with `ToString` as exemplified in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has already said, your problem happens because you try to assign to a string property (`TextBoxAns.Text`) the result of adding two integers (another integer) and this is not allowed by the C# language without a proper conversion.
However none has pointed to your attention another big problem in your code.

What happen if the user doesn't type a number in your textboxes?
What happen if a user ask for division and type a zero in textBox2.Text?

In both situations your code will crash because, in the first case, the `Convert.ToInt32` cannot handle not numeric strings and, in the second case, you get a division by zero.

You need to be careful when you deal with user inputs....
The correct approach is using the [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method as in the following example for the divide button

```
   private void buttonDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        int val1;
        int val2;

        if(!Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out val1))
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid number!");
             return;
        }
        if(!Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out val2))
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid number!");
             return;
        }
        if(val2 == 0)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by zero!");
             return;
        }
        textBoxAns.Text = (val1 / val2).ToString();

        // The line above is an integer division, without decimals returned.
        // If you want a floating point result then you need
        textBoxAns.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(val1) / val2).ToString();

   }
```